# calendar comparison is not working

Tags: java

i have written this code and its not working......

indate = "13/1/2011"

```
Calendar cd1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] StartDate = split(inDate.trim(),"/");
        cd1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(StartDate[0]));
        cd1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(StartDate[1]));
        cd1.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(StartDate[2]));

currentDate ="14/1/2011"
        String CurrentDate = com.connection.loginscreen.currentDate;
        Calendar cd2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] resultc = split(CurrentDate.trim(), "/");
        cd2.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(resultc[2]));
        cd2.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(resultc[0]));
        cd2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(resultc[1]));

        if (cd1.before(cd2))
        {
            check ="1";
        }
```

it is not working.....

Comment: sorry current date is 1/14/2011.

Comment: Try debugging it by doing a `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(cd1.getTime()))` on each calendar value and see if you are parsing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the parsing yourself. To convert a String to a Date, use a DateFormat, like this:

```
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");   
    String indate = "13/1/2011";
    Date cd1 = f.parse(indate);
    String currentDate ="1/14/2011";
    DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    Date cd2 = f2.parse(currentDate);
    if (cd1.before(cd2))
    {
        check ="1";
    }
```

Check the [SimpleDateFormat javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to see what patterns are defined and how it is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly not what you want:

```
cd1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(StartDate[1]));
```

`Calendar.MONTH` is zero-based... whereas humans usually read/write months in a 1-based fashion.

Leaving the details aside though, you really shouldn't be writing parsing code yourself anyway, unless you have a *particularly* weird format which isn't handled by libraries. If you really want to stick with the Java libraries, use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse it. Doing the parsing yourself will lead to mistakes like the one above and the one that jk pointed out. It's like building XML up by hand from strings: *don't do it - use libraries*.

Personally though, I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all date/time work in Java. It's a much nicer API.

Comment: @keuleJ: So do I. It's just one of the *many* reasons to use Joda Time.